# android.support.design.chip.Chip

Tags: android, android-chips

I'm face to a problem with chip component on android.
I try to implemente a chip like this:

```
    <android.support.design.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/tags"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world"/>
```

But when I launch my app I have this error:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59: Binary XML file line #59: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.chip.Chip
>
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59:
>   Error inflating class android.support.design.chip.Chip
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this
>   component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a
>   descendant).

My style is already an AppCompact.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use app theme to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge` inspite of `AppCompat` if you want to use `android.support.design.chip.Chip`.

> **Reason:**
>
> **`Chip`** component relies on new `MaterialComponents` theme, so is why the
>   crash occurs. **`Bridge`** theme here are treated as `AppCompat` but
>   provides new `MaterialComponents` theme when needed.

Comment: thanks for your response but it the problem is always present

Comment: You changed your `AppTheme` to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge` right?, because i was having issue and i solved by changing to this.